# Protractor function error generating random option Selectui

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, protractor

```
  <tr class="form-row form-row-odd form-row-err  form-cols-2 form_element_company_id">
    <th>Company&nbsp;
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </th>
    <td>
        <select name="company_id" class="selectmenu input-inf select2-initialized select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <option value="">— None —</option>
            <option value="1" class="sub-option-0 ">Option 1</option>
            <option value="14" class="sub-option-0 ">Option 2</option>
            <option value="45" class="sub-option-1 " data-parent-name="Option 2="14">Option 2-1</option>
            <option value="46" class="sub-option-1 " data-parent-name="Option 2" data-parent-id="14">Option 2-2</option>
            <option value="47" class="sub-option-1 " data-parent-name="Option 2" data-parent-id="14">Option 2-3</option>
            <option value="29" class="sub-option-0 ">Option 3</option>
            <option value="30" class="sub-option-0 ">Option 4</option>
            <option value="31" class="sub-option-0 ">Option 5</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to create a function that will automaticaly pick an option from the select2 name="company_id" :
So far I have tried :

```
   function setUserCompany(selector){    
    var companyField = selector;
        if (companyField.length == 0) { 
        return; 
        }
        var options = companyField.find('option')
    if (options.length == 0) {
    return; 
    }
    var randomIdx = Math.floor((Math.random() * selector.length)+1);
    var randomValue = $(options.get(randomIdx)).attr('value');
    companyField.select2().val(randomValue).trigger('change'); 
    }
```

^ doesn't seem to work properly aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to get the random value or click on random option. You almost done just missed on getting the select box by css name. Try this,

```
var companySelectBox = browser.element(by.css('[name="company_id"]'));
companySelectBox.all(by.tagName('option')).then(function(options){
    //random id between option length
    var randomId = Math.floor((Math.random() * options.length)+1);
    console.log('random id ' + randomId); 
    options[randomId].getText().then(function(text){
        console.log('random option text ' + text); 
    });
    //click on random option  
    options[randomId].click();
    //TODO: whatever other task similar 
});
```